# Swift Subclass google maps infoWindow

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

Is it possible to subclass google maps info Window. I know that i can create my own window but i really like the shadow from google info window. I know with MKMapview this is possible but i want to do it with google.

Comment: Hi, can you post a screenshot of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Inherit your ViewController from GMSMapViewDelegate and make it delegate of same. After that you can use following delegate method to put your customize infoWindow either using a nib or creating one programatically:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
    let infoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomInfoWindow", owner: self.view, options: nil)!.first! as! CustomInfoWindow
    infoWindow.title.text = marker.title
    return infoWindow
}
```

Comment: I wanted to preserve the shadow of the default info window and jus add my view inside of it.